# is synchronized by class name in a function will be valid across extended classes?

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a methode foo in base class uses Synchronized (class name) , and two classes A and B that extends the base class. if i called foo from A instance and B instance in two different thread are they gonna be Synchronized. here's a sample code :

```
class BaseClass { 
        void foo() {
        synchronized(BaseClass.class)   
            // do something like increment count 
        }   
    }


    class A extends BaseClass {
    }


    class B extends BaseClass {
    }

    A a = new A(); 
    B b = new B();
    //in thread 1
    a.foo() ; 
    //in thread 2
    b.foo() ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will be synchronized across *all* instances of *all* classes extending `BaseClass` (including `BaseClass` itself). The `BaseClass.class` reference will basically be a single reference for the whole classloader. Do you really want that?

*Usually*, when synchronization is required, static methods should synchronize on something static, and instance methods should synchronize on something related to the instance. Personally I don't like synchronizing on either `this` or a `Class` reference - as both of those references are available elsewhere, so other code could synchronize on the same monitor, making it hard to reason about the synchronization. Instead, I would tend to have:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object instanceLock = new Object();

    public void doSomething() {
        synchronized (instanceLock) {
            // Stuff
        }
    }
}

public class Bar {
    private static final Object staticLock = new Object();

    public static void doSomething() {
        synchronized (staticLock) {
            // Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

(I typically actually just use `lock` as the name; I've just made it more explicit here for clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are synchronizing on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is synchronized, even though sequence of thread execution is not guaranteed.